# Regarding Muir Woods Shuttle

Tags: usa, public-transport, national-parks, san-francisco, san-francisco-bay-area

When you reserve a seat on the [Muir Woods shuttle](https://gomuirwoods.com/muir/shuttleInfo), the system is only asking you about the time you want to board the shuttle at [Pohono St.](https://goo.gl/maps/GRbkkEhALEhFRcjG6) (which is, I believe, the only pick up location; but correct me if I'm wrong). But it doesn't ask for the time you'd like to go back from Muir Woods to Pohono St. At the same time, all tickets are round-trip. So I'm assuming you can take any shuttle back. Is that right? And if so, is there a schedule of shuttles that go from Muir Woods back to Pohono St.?

Comment: The bus times in the reservation page are at about 10 to 20 minute intervals. It would be safe to assume the return rides are at the same frequency.

Comment: Note that because of COVID, the shuttle is currently not running and is scheduled to start running only on weekends on June 19th. You can otherwise make a parking reservation directly at the Muir Woods parking lot and skip the shuttle entirely (or if you're up for a hike, do as I like to do and park elsewhere in the area and hike in/out so you get the full experience of ascending/descending into the forest, but note that there's a rather significant elevation change involved in any such hike).

Comment: @ZachLipton Unfortunately I'll be without a car but otherwise I would ascend into the forest. Or is there public transportation to the point where I start ascending?

Comment: @user77409 Unfortunately the public transit options aren't the greatest. You can [take a couple of semi-infrequent buses from San Francisco](https://bit.ly/2S2xvGT) that get you a mile or so from the main entrance if you prefer (I've never done that hike, can't speak for how scenic it is). It's also [a great bike trip](https://www.sfchronicle.com/travel/article/How-to-ride-your-bike-to-Muir-Woods-12919484.php) if you're interested in that, though be sure to consider the elevation gain/loss, especially for the second Alice Eastwood route, which is beautiful but not at all flat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems I found the information that answers my question at least partially (see below). It might change when the shuttle starts operating (June 19, 2021), but then I hope it will be updated on [the website where I took this information from](https://marintransit.org/routes/66).

> Service is currently operated every 10-20 minutes on weekends and holidays only. Service to Muir Woods from Pohono operates from 8:30 am to 3:00 pm and return service from the Park operates from 10:30 am to 6:00 pm (or earlier depending upon Park closure times).